# How to study Inquiry and questions on their own?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, philosophy-of-language

I was wondering,that we can think about love,god,faith etc... by asking questions about them.

But  what about questions themselves?

How can we think about them? They don't seem to have any tangible structure that we can base studies on.

Moreover,we need to ask questions to know questions; which seems circular. 
How can one then successfully "Understand" Inquiry?

Answer (score 1):

You are being too hard on yourself.  Inquiry is not one "thing."    One must start somewhere.  Ask yourself a question.  Answer it for yourself.  Then share the question and the answer with another, or several others.  Have them answer the question and address your answer (and others). Make revisions to your question and your answer based on the others' answer.  Repeat.

Comment: These things are studied by metaphysics and a major part of this is a study of the form of our questions. The answers are often found by recognising the false assumptions that they contain.

Comment: @PeterJ Would you elaborate or cite sources?

Comment: @Logan Luther Sure thing. Metaphysics studies 'love, God, faith' by way of ontology and epistemology. It attempts to answer questions about these phenomena by logical analysis. More often than not it is found that the answers (or the problems we meet in answering them)   are contained in the questions. We ask 'Does God exist', and when we try to answer we end up realising that we are not quite clear what we mean by our terms. Defining our terms then becomes the problem and we may end up concluding that the answer to our question is 'yes' or 'no' depending on our definitions. Big topic.

Comment: PS - On reflection your question is more interesting than I first thought. But I find it a little unclear so cannot offer a direct answer.

Comment: @PeterJ thank you. I was also bewildered by the ambiguity,hence the question.